# Hazelcast eviction and MapStore

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Does Hazelcast call `store()` or `storeAll()` in MapStores before the eviction?

I've wired the map to MapStore and it works fine.But I am wondering when Hazelcast wants to do the eviction. Does it call MapStore methods before clearing the cache?

Answer (score 2):

Each operation is reflected to the MapStore on the partition thread so it does not have to call `storeAll` on eviction and it does not call it (if write through enabled). If write behind the map will be evicted, but the scheduled MapStore operations will run.

Comment: The write mode that I am using is "write-behind". The delay is 10 minutes. Does it call storeAll() before eviction?